# How to get names of the files which contain the specified text only

Tags: files, grep

I have a directory named "labels" in which there are text files which contain labels for "cat" or "dog" or both on separate lines.
Contents of files in labels directory are:

```
cat labels/1.txt
cat

cat labels/2.txt
dog

cat labels/3.txt
cat  
dog
```

I want to get the names of files which contain label "cat" only. I tried following command:

```
ls labels | grep -Rwl "cat"   
labels/1.txt  
labels/3.txt
```

But this command returns the names of those files which contain "cat" or both. But my requirement is to get those file names which contain only "cat", not both "cat" and "dog".
Similarly when I try to get names of those files which contain "dog" only. If I search in the same fashion then it returns file names which contain "dog" or both labels.

```
ls labels | grep -Rwl "dog"
labels/2.txt  
labels/3.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `grep` twice: a) for listing all files with `cat`, then b) sieve out `dog`-containing ones. Use `-l` and `-L`, respectively, where `-l` lists filenames with matches and `-L` filenames without matches:

```
grep -L 'dog' $(grep -l 'cat' <list of files>)
```

See `man grep`:

> -L, --files-without-match
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have  been  printed.   The scanning will stop on the first match.
>
> -l, --files-with-matches
>
> Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print  the  name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.

Comment: This could break with file names containing spaces, +1 btw.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Good point, however with  `-z` and `-Z` it seems that `grep` is quite well equipped even for these cases.

Comment: @FelixJN, grep might be equipped to use NULs as filenames separators, but most shells aren't. That is, at least the command substitution won't be able to deal with them, except in zsh if you set `IFS=$'\0'`. In Bash you'd need to use `mapfile` to populate a temporary array. Though in Bash you could just use `set -f` and set `IFS=$'\n'` to at least deal with any characters except the newline

Comment: For NUL separated filenames, you can pipe the output of the first `grep` into `xargs grep` instead of using command substitution.  e.g. `grep -zwLR dog labels/ | xargs -0r grep -lw cat`

Comment: Thank you so much for help. It solved the problem. Cheers

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity It's not only spaces, it's every character in `$IFS` and in Bourne-like shells other than `zsh`, all wildcard characters and that unquoted `$(...)` invokes split+glob.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `grep` and `xargs` (`-R` which you're already using is a GNU `grep` extension anyway, though `-r` is preferable there):

```
grep -rwlZ cat labels/ | xargs -r0 grep -wL dog
```

Would list the files that contain at least one `cat` word and no `dog` word (*word* in that context meaning: "not surrounded by *word characters*", *word characters* being alphanumerical characters and underscore). Replace `-w` with `-x` to search for lines whose entire content *is* `cat`/`dog`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to list the names of the files that contain "cat" but not "dog", try something like this, using `find` and GNU `awk` (or any other `awk` that supports `ENDFILE` blocks as this is a GNU extension to `awk`):

```
$ find labels/ -type f -exec awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    /\<cat\>/ { cat = 1 };
    /\<dog\>/ { dog = 1 };

    ENDFILE {
      if (cat == 1 && dog == 0) {
        print FILENAME
      };
      cat = 0;
      dog = 0;
    }' {} +
labels/file1.txt
```

Or you could use `perl` instead of `awk`:

```
$ find labels/ -type f -exec perl -l -n -e  '
    $cat = 1 if m/\bcat\b/i;
    $dog = 1 if m/\bdog\b/i;
    if (eof) {
      print $ARGV if ($cat && ! $dog);
      $cat=0;
      $dog=0;
    }' {} +
labels/file1.txt
```

The output from both awk and perl versions above was produced with the following files in the `labels/` subdirectory:

```
$ tail labels/*
==> labels/file1.txt <==
cat

==> labels/file2.txt <==
dog

==> labels/file3.txt <==
cat
dog
```

`labels/file1.txt` is the only filename printed because it's the only file that contains "cat" and doesn't contain "dog".

Comment: BTW, if you're going to use the output filenames with `xargs` or as args to another program or script, I strongly recommend using NUL as the filename separator, so that it works safely and reliably with any filenames, even if they contain spaces or newlines or other annoying characters.  With awk, add `-v ORS='\0'` to the command-line options.  With perl, remove the `-l` option and add the line `chomp;` before the `$cat = 1.....` line, and change the `print $ARGV if ...` to `print "$ARGV\000" if ...`.

Comment: Actually, on a GNU system, `ls labels | grep -Rwl "cat"` does grep the contents. The man page says of `-r`, that "Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory." (and yes, that applies to `-R` too) The output they get would also match that.

Comment: @ilkkachu that's right, it does do that.  so the `ls labels` is actually useless and effectively does nothing.   even so, the OP can't do what they want with a single grep alone.   `grep -Rzl` piped into `xargs -0r grep -l` would be a good start....but IMO find -exec and awk or perl is better.

Comment: yep, indeed it is.

Comment: and for whole word matches (which I totally missed was in the OP's requirements), my awk script above should use `/\<cat\>/` and `/\<dog\>/`, and the perl version should use `m/\bcat\b/i` and `m/\bdog\b/i`.

Comment: Thank you so much problem solved.

Comment: @Naveed if one or more of the answers here solved your problem, you should pick the one you like best and select it as the Accepted answer (click on the big tick/check mark to the top-left of the answer).  Optionally upvote it too and/or upvote any other answers you liked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, assuming I understood correctly, that all the files are in the same directory, and that their extension is `txt`:

```
$ cat a.txt 
cat
dog
$ cat b.txt 
cat
dog
$ cat c.txt 
cat
$ cat d.txt 
dog
```

Then the command:

```bsh
# scan the directory for txt files
$ find /dir -type f -name ".txt" | while IFS= read -r i; do 
    # if it's false that the file does match both 'cat' and 'dog'
    # grep 'cat'
    if ! [[ $(grep -wl 'cat' "$i") && $(grep -wl 'dog' "$i") ]]; then 
      grep -wl 'cat' "$i"
    fi
  done
c.txt
```

The `-l` option in `grep` is useful here because it stops scanning after finding the first match, hence the files are not parsed entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *; do diff -q <(sort -u "$f") <(echo cat) >/dev/null && echo "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

To find files in the labels/ directory that *only* contain the string "`cats`" on one line, you could compare the hashsums of each of those files to the "correct" hashsum:

```bsh
find labels -type f -exec sh -c 'for arg do [ "$(md5sum < "$arg")" = "54b8617eca0e54c7d3c8e6732c6b687a  -" ] && printf "%s\n" "$arg"; done' findsh {} +
```

The work of finding the files is done with `find labels -type f` and the filtering is done inside the `-exec sh -c '...' findsh {} +` portion. That inner portion loops over every incoming file (given to it by `find`, as many as will fit in each call) and ask `md5sum` for the file's checksum. If the checksum matches, then print the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty straightforward way using Perl. Note `glob` only works on the current directory. The `s` modifier on the regex lets it search over all the lines of the file at once.

```
perl -lE 'say for glob "*"' | perl -lnE 'open $file, "<", $_; say if join("", <$file>) =~ /cat/s
```